# PHP Model not returning result

Tags: php, opencart

I have a recursive model function as such:

```
public function buildPaths ($category_id, $current_path = array()) {
    if (!empty ($current_path)):
        $output = $current_path;
    else:
        $output = array(0 => $category_id);
    endif;

    $query = $this->db->query ("
        SELECT parent_id 
        FROM {$this->prefix}category 
        WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "' 
        AND status = '1'");

    if ($query->row['parent_id'] != 0):
        $output[] = $query->row['parent_id'];
        $this->buildPaths($query->row['parent_id'], $output);
    else:
        $output = array_reverse ($output);
        $path = implode ('_', $output);
        return (string)$path;
    endif;
}
```

Passing in a value of 40 for instance should return the following:

`3_40`

When I echo out the variable `$path` within the model it does display the correct value, but when I call the function via my controller ie:

`$result = $this->model_catalog_category->buildPaths(40);`

`$result` returns empty.

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Comment: You're only `return`ing in your final else statement - if there is a match to `if ($query->row['parent_id'] != 0):`, you're not returning anything.

Comment: correct, it's a recursive function that calls itself until the parent_id of 0 is reached, then formats the $output array into a string and returns $path.  Nothing should be returned until then.

Comment: Ok I see ... I got confused because normally I don't return within the else statement.  Works perfect now thanks!

Comment: Can you add an answer with your corrected code, and accept it when you can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [andrewsi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315962/andrewsi) for this answer:

```
public function buildPaths ($category_id, $current_path = array()) {
    if (!empty ($current_path)):
        $output = $current_path;
    else:
        $output = array(0 => $category_id);
    endif;

    $query = $this->db->query ("
        SELECT parent_id 
        FROM {$this->prefix}category 
        WHERE category_id = '" . (int)$category_id . "' 
        AND status = '1'");

    if ($query->row['parent_id'] != 0):
        $output[] = $query->row['parent_id'];
        return $this->buildPaths($query->row['parent_id'], $output);
    else:
        $output = array_reverse ($output);
        $path = implode ('_', $output);
        return (string)$path;
    endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an if flow control and return on else try to put out of ot else

```
if ($query->row['parent_id'] != 0):
        $output[] = $query->row['parent_id'];
        $this->buildPaths($query->row['parent_id'], $output);
    else:
        $output = array_reverse ($output);
        $path = implode ('_', $output);
    endif;

        return (string)$path;
```